# Module django.contrib.auth.context_processors not found

Tags: python, django, eclipse

When my django code gets to:

```
res = render_to_response ('server_form.html', {'items':items}, context_instance =  RequestContext(request),)
```

I get the following output from the browser.  Why?
The worrying part is this has only happened after I installed dajax/dajaxice, until then everything worked.  I did have trouble getting dajaxice to work so I could have disturbed things but the question is what has changed to get this problem? As far as I can see settings.py is correct.  I've searched for days for a solution without success so any help solving this most welcome. I'm running this under Eclipse Indigo.  Where in the file system is/should be django.contrib.auth under ubuntu?

**Output from web browser:**

```
Error importing request processor module django.contrib.auth.context_processors: "No module named context_processors"Request Method:    GET
Request URL:    http://x.x.x.x:8000/helloServ
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    Error importing request processor module django.contrib.auth.context_processors: "No module named context_processors"
Exception Location: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/context.py in get_standard_processors, line 84
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.6
Python Version: 2.6.6
Python Path:    ['/home/pjr/workspace/mysite2/src/mysite2', '/home/pjr/bin/eclipse372/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.5.2013052819/pysrc', '/home/pjr/workspace/mysite2/src', '/home/pjr/bin/eclipse372/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913/pysrc', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
Server time:    Mon, 3 Feb 2014 17:26:11 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the context processors are currently in your settings.py configuration file ?
There should be somewhere :

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

If this doens't help, according to your error, you should be able to find your django source files in `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/`.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Yes all the above are set.  In the end I found the problem which is that django.contrib.auth is not supported under the python/django installed under ubuntu 10.04, it has django 1.1.1.  Having re-written the render_to_response line to comply with django 1.1.1 the problem is solved.